# How can I investigate correlations between tumor location and surface-receptor expression in R-studio?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, multivariate-analysis

I am not sure what statistical approach/model I should use for the following example - so I hope you can helt with some inputs.

I have four different possible tumour locations in the head area - number 1, 2, 3 and 4.
I want to investigate whether specific expression of different surface-receptors correlates with specific tumor locations. I have ten different types of surface-receptors that can be expressed.

How I can I analyze whether specific surface-receptor expressions (or combinations) correlate with presentation of tumors in specific locations?

Can you help with what model/approach I should use?

Comment: In my opinion, [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) could be one of the choice. But I am not sure about it.  I want to know what kind of model could be used too. So +1 wishing someone answer this question.